# Best Way to Update Object within another Object

Tags: java

I am making a Card Game in Java with server-client code. On the server I created Game and Player object classes, so that the Game class contains two player instance objects. What I want to do is, whenever I update the internal state of a player, I want a method in the Game class to be called that will send the updated states of the players to the client. How should I go about doing this?

So In my code, below I want it where when a player calls grow(), the internal state of health is updated, and I want the dispatch() method in the Game class to be called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When do it:

```
Player player = new Player();
player.grow();
```

The method:

```
void grow() {
    health += 25;
    Game game = new Game();
    game.dispatch(health);
}
```

so, in class Game you have a method:

```
void dispatch(int health) {
    //send updated player obj to client
}
```

Comment: I ended up just calling a method in the game method that called a method in player. And then called dispatch after that. so dispatch stays within the game class